# Slow queries with LIMIT (Active Record `first` method)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I observed that running `Model.where(*condition with 3 integer indexes*).first` takes too much time on big tables.

`first` adds sorting by `id`, so it probabably should take and sort all of 1.5 million records:

```
Game.where(private: 0, status: 0).first
DEBUG -- :   Game Load (__1278.6ms__)
SELECT  "games".* FROM "games" WHERE "games"."private" = 0 AND "games"."status" = 0
__ORDER BY "games"."id" ASC__ LIMIT 1
```

Removing `first` turns things much faster:

```
Game.where(private: 0, status: 0)
DEBUG -- :   Game Load (__68.0ms__)
SELECT "games".* FROM "games" WHERE "games"."private" = 0 AND "games"."status" = 0
```

However, if I manually remove sorting things are still going not so fast:

```
Game.where(private: 0, status: 0).order(nil).first
DEBUG -- :   Game Load (__323.7ms__)
SELECT  "games".* FROM "games" WHERE "games"."private" = 0 AND "games"."status" = 0 LIMIT 1
```

Does anyone know what's the cause of this? Now I consider using `scope.to_a.first` which seems to be much faster.

Explain plan for the first query is:

```
1. Limit (cost=0.43..59.68 rows=1 width=59)
2. -> Index Scan using games_pkey on games (cost=0.43..90007.49 rows=1519 width=59)
3. Filter: ?
```

**UPD**

It's strange but today I see other results for second query (now it's being executed almost instantly):

```
Game.where(private: 0, status: 0).order(nil).first
DEBUG -- :   Game Load (__2.5ms__)
SELECT  "games".* FROM "games"  WHERE "games"."private" = 0 AND "games"."status" = 0 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What version of ActiveRecord are you using?

Comment: Obvious question but you do have an index on games.id.. right?

Comment: What version of Rails/pg gem/Postgres? Also have you tried running `explain` on the query?

Comment: Are you sure that the second query does perform a request to DB ? It must just create an ActiveRecord::Relation object without performing a query.

Comment: Did you include `limit(1)` when you run explain on that?

Comment: @jphenow Rails and active_record 4.1.6, Postgres 9.3, gem pg-0.17.1. I provided an explain output for query with `first`, but adding limit(1) seem to be very fast (less than 10 ms).

Comment: @chumakoff it returns me result in console, seems like it's fetched from db.

Comment: @ilan-berci I think it's created autmatically as games.id is the primary_key, isn't it?

Comment: @Ajaxy, yes it is.. but sometimes weird migrations of oblivious users can mess up your db.. never hurts to check.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Without posting any details of the query plan it is very hard to debug the issue. There may be several factor that are causing a temporary slow down of the query, factors not connected with the code itself rather with the way the database stores the data.

Just relying on the execution time of the query may not truly expose whether a query is efficient or not.

Generally speaking, the `LIMIT` requires more resource if there is a sort condition involved, as the database have to sort the data internally in order to extract the N records. Of course, if the attribute used in the sort clause is not indexed, then the query will be even more inefficient.

ActiveRecord exposes both `first` and `take`. If you run

```
Game.where(private: 0, status: 0).first
```

then ActiveRecord will sort the records by primary key (unless you specify a sorting column) whereas if you use

```
Game.where(private: 0, status: 0).take
```

ActiveRecord will query the database and just get the first one. Which solution is better, well it depends. In the second case the result is unpredictable because the database will return the data in whatever order it wants.

Generally, applying a sort condition is quite cheap. But again, you need to check the query plan.

From the console, just append `.explain` to dump the query plan of a specific query. For example

```
puts Game.where(private: 0, status: 0).explain
puts Game.where(private: 0, status: 0).order(:id).explain
```

Comment: @Ajaxy I would give this a shot, this should basically be doing what you're looking for, unless you really are concerned about an order. If you check source of [take](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/take) and subsequently [find_take](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_take) you'll see that its basically what we discussed in the comments above

Comment: @jphenow The problem is I'm actually using not `first` but `first_or_create` method. So I ended up with `Game.where(...).order(nil).first_or_create ` .

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have provided explain plan at the bottom of my topic.